# DropDownList Value is always invalid in MVC 3

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have one contact form, that send the email to one of Address selected from a dropDownList.
But when post the form, the DropDownList is always invalid.

Full Model:

```
public class ContactModels
{
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Nome não pode conter mais de 100 caracteres.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Empresa")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Endereço de email é obrigatório.")]
    [RegularExpression("[a-z0-9_\\+-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_\\+-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\\.([a-z]{2,4})$", ErrorMessage = "Email não é válido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telefone é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Nome não pode conter mais de 15 caracteres.")]
    public string Fone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Mensagem")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O texto do email é obrigatório.")]
    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Nome não pode conter mais de 500 caracteres.")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Anexo")]
    public string filePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Departamento")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> dropDownitems
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] {
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Comercial", Value = "1"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Financeiro", Value = "2"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "Parceria", Value = "3"},
                new SelectListItem { Text = "RH/Curriculos", Value = "4"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Full View:

```
@model MvcAtakComBr.Models.ContactModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contacts";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="main_title">Contato</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "contato", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Company)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fone)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fone)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dropDownitems)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("dropDownitems")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dropDownitems)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        arquivo:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="filePath" id="filePath" />
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { cols = 35, rows = 5 })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </p>
}
```

Always ModelState.IsValid is False. it's not accepting the value. "Value 'address4@email.com'" is invalid". I've tried replace the value by number, or a single word and did not succeed.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a strongly typed helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedItem,  
    new SelectList(Model.dropDownitems, "Value", "Text"),
    "-- Select an item --"
)
```

where obviously you will add the `SelectedItem` property on your view model to hold the selected value:

```
[Required]
public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

As far as the validation error message you are getting for the Email field is concerned you might need to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

What does ContactModels look like?  Also, what is your full ViewModel?  Are other values being set correctly, or is it only the dropdown?

At a wild guess, I'd say its a binding error in your controller.  You'll need to specify the prefix on the model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix="MyViewModelName")]ContactModels contactForm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         //send the email
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I do hav more values. All the other values works fine. I've updated my question with the full model and view.
controller:
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(ContactModels contactForm)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {